# jQuery DataTables datetime-moment is not parsing dates correctly, or at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables, momentjs

I've built a table using the jQuery DataTables plugin. Here's [my broken Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7NKYvTCnTyIAypPuhbQU?p=preview). It has a column of dates that I'm trying to parse into `MMMM YYYY` format, except it doesn't parse at all. The plugin I'm using is [datetime-moment.js](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18#Ordering-plug-in), which provides the following example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fn.dataTable.moment( 'HH:mm MMM D, YY' );
    $.fn.dataTable.moment( 'dddd, MMMM Do, YYYY' );

    $('#example').DataTable();
});
```

My code, which doesn't work, looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fn.dataTable.moment( 'MMMM YYYY' );
    $(".data-table").DataTable({
        data: tableData,
        columns: [{
            "data": recordCol
        }, 
        {
            "data": stateName
        }, 
        {
            "data": dateCol
        },
        {            
            "data": valCol  
        }]
    });

    d3.selectAll("thead th").each(function(d, i) {
        if (i === 0) {
            this.textContent = "record type";
        } else if (i === 1) {
            this.textContent = stateName;  
        } else if (i === 2) {
            this.textContent = "date"; 
        } else if (i === 3) {
            this.textContent = "treatment episodes";          
        }
    });  
}); //closes $(document).ready(function() {
```

Can anyone demonstrate a solution (here, again is [my broken Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7NKYvTCnTyIAypPuhbQU?p=preview)), such that the column parses and displays correctly into `MMMM YYYY` format, and also sorts correctly in chronological order?

Comment: The table doesn't render at all for me on that code example you put up. Are you sure it's not just a datatables config issue?

Comment: It's showing up fine on my end; it appears at the bottom of the page, after the graphs.

Comment: Looks like it's a firefox thing. Loaded ok in chrome.

Comment: Loading fine in Firefox here, but I'll make a note to test that further, once I find a solution for parsing the date column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to mention from what date format you are changing it from and to. I have forked that and updated it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/pzUubWuyzpdwD3NwvQUI?p=preview) to check.

You need to make the following changes to your [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7NKYvTCnTyIAypPuhbQU?p=preview).

Add the below js as dataTableTime.js to your plunker.

```
(function( factory ) {
"use strict";

if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
    // AMD
    define( ['jquery'], function ( $ ) {
        return factory( $, window, document );
    } );
}
else if ( typeof exports === 'object' ) {
    // CommonJS
    module.exports = function (root, $) {
        if ( ! root ) {
            root = window;
        }

        if ( ! $ ) {
            $ = typeof window !== 'undefined' ?
                require('jquery') :
                require('jquery')( root );
        }

        return factory( $, root, root.document );
    };
}
else {
    // Browser
    factory( jQuery, window, document );
}
}
(function( $, window, document ) {


$.fn.dataTable.render.moment = function ( from, to, locale ) {
// Argument shifting
if ( arguments.length === 1 ) {
    locale = 'en';
    to = from;
    from = 'MMM D, Y h:mm:ss A';
}
else if ( arguments.length === 2 ) {
    locale = 'en';
}

return function ( d, type, row ) {
    var m = window.moment( d, from, locale, true );

    // Order and type get a number value from Moment, everything else
    // sees the rendered value
    return m.format( type === 'sort' || type === 'type' ? 'x' : to );
};
};
  }));
```

Add the pages in below order in `index.html`

```
<script src="dataTableTime.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Remove or comment the code in line 1118 from `script.js` i.e. the below code

```
$.fn.dataTable.moment( 'MMMM YYYY' );
```

Change Datatable code as below by adding `columnDefs` to it

```
$(".data-table").DataTable({
    data: tableData,

    columns: [{
      "data": recordCol
    }, {
      "data": stateName
    }, {
     // "data": dateCol

        "data": dateCol//,
        //render: function(d){
        //    return moment(d).format("MMMM YYYY");
        //}          

    }, {            
      "data": valCol//"values[, ].y"  
    }],
    "columnDefs": [
      {
        "targets": 2,
        render: $.fn.dataTable.render.moment('EEE MMM DD YYYY hh:mm:ss TZD (zzz)', 'MMMM YYYY')
      }
    ]
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know enough about that plugin, but I did find a solution for this when I was using datatables a while back. You can slap a render option onto the datatable column you want to format:

```
columns: [{
      "data": recordCol
    }, {
      "data": stateName
    }, {
      "data": dateCol, render: function(d){
         return moment(d).format('MMMM YYYY');
         },
    }, {            
      "data": valCol  
    }]
```

I know it's not exactly what  you were looking for, but hopefully it helps.

Comment: I did try that already (in fact, it's commented-out in my Plunker, though I omitted it from my question). The problem with your suggestion, as I'm sure you're familiar, is that the dates don't sort correctly. All of the dates in April come first and and the ones September comes last.

Comment: I ended up switching to tabulator which to me feels a bit easier to use. There's also a date sort option built in. You may want to have a look at it: http://tabulator.info/docs/3.3#sorting